# Can not Display the Images

Tags: php

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php    

$dbhost = 'localhost';    
$dbuser = 'root';    
$dbpass = '';  
$dbname = 'moviefone';    
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);  
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);    

// Check connection    
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {  
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();    
}    

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new_hindi LIMIT 4") or die(mysql_error());    $info = NULL;   

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))    
{    
    $info = $row ;    
};    


?>
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="sub-column1">
    <a class="new_movies" href="#"><span>New</span></a> <a href="#"><img src=
    "%3C?php%20echo%20$info[">" width="140" height="200" class="new-img"
    /&gt;</a> <a class="img_titles" href="#"><?php echo $info["title"];?></a>
    <a class="new_english" href="#"><span>New</span></a>
</div>
```

I can not display the image and the title. It's showing no errors but the image is blank.

Comment: Line breaks and readable code are your friend when asking questions.

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they are deprecated. See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for details. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: could you post your full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `$info` array is not in scope.
You have to assign the values in your loop to another variable or push info to another array in scope.

Comment: thanks it worked but now the now image is repeating .how can i display the first four entry?

Answer (score 0):

`$info` was not in scope where you were using it. You need to put the HTML into the `while()`

Usual warnings... please don't use this type of mysql connection it has been depreciated, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

```
<?php    

    $dbhost = 'localhost';    
    $dbuser = 'root';    
    $dbpass = '';  
    $dbname = 'moviefone';    
    $con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);    

    // Check connection    
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {  
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();    
    }    

    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new_hindi LIMIT 4") or die(mysql_error());   

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){    ?>

        <div class="sub-column1">
            <a class="new_movies" href="#"><span>New</span></a> <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $row['image'];?>" width="140" height="200" class="new-img" /></a> <a class="img_titles" href="#"><?php echo $row["title"];?></a>
            <a class="new_english" href="#"><span>New</span></a>
        </div>      

        <?php 
    }   


?>
```

Comment: You may need to change `$row['image']` to match the name you have given the image column in the database, but it should work provided the query is returning results

Comment: well i have got it worked but i want four images to be displayed but only one image is repeating in four different place.

Comment: Are you sure that the data being selected doesn't have the same image each time. Try putting `print_r($row);` in the `while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )`....